# Avoid returning "Undefined offset 0" table is empty using Laravel Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Currently, I have `tbl_projtask` from MySQL

and I have this query in my laravel app. This works fine if the `tbl_projtask` has rows.

```
$projtask = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * from tbl_projtask WHERE projCode = '".$request->projCode."' AND taskCode = '".$request->taskCode."' AND deleted = 0")
```

But when I truncate the table.

This query returns me an error like this

```
"message": "Undefined offset: 0",
```

I'm using `count()` to validated if there's data inside the table.

something like this

```
if(count($projtask)){
     //Some codes
}else{
     //Some codes
}
```

If I truncate the table. The code gives me the error stated above. But if not truncated and has some rows. The code of `count()` is working fines. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: what are you doing in that `else` block?

Answer (score 0):

Since your are comparing to the integer count of the table data.

Change condition to something like this.

```
 if(count($projtask) > 0){
         //Some codes
    }else{
         //Some codes
    }
```

Also you can use query builder.

```
    $projtask = DB::table('tbl_projtask')
    ->select("*")
    ->where(['projCode' => $request->projCode, 'taskCode'=> $request->taskCode, 'deleted' => 0 ])
    ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing either `->get()` or `->first()`, if you choose `get()` this will give you an expected return of populated or empty collection, ie:

```
$projtask = DB::connection('mysql')->select("SELECT * from tbl_projtask WHERE projCode = '".$request->projCode."' AND taskCode = '".$request->taskCode."' AND deleted = 0")->get()
```

so by doing so you can now check if it is empty or not, ie:

```
if(empty($projtask) === true){
  // Handle logic if the collection is empty here
}

// else return the $projtask
return $projtask;
```